# How do I initialize all inherited classes in python3.2?

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, super

I'm working using python3.2 and I have a class that inherits two classes.  The sub-classes `__init__` functions of the child classes have different signatures.  In brief, is is possible to create an object of the Parent that calls the `__init__` of each child class?

## Background

Say I have the following python3.2 code

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.ver = "the ver"
        print("A::__init__ .... name = %s" % name)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self,):
        self.name = "the name"
        print("B::__init__")
 
    def foo(self,):
        print("B::foo.   The name is >>%s<<" % self.name)

class C(B,A):
    def  __init__(self,):
        print("C::__init__")
        super(B, self).__init__()
        super(A, self).__init__('waaa')
```

I can create an instance of `A` and `B`

```
>>> a = A('myplace')
A::__init__ .... name = myplace
>>> b = B()
B::__init__
```

However creating an instance of `C` fails.

```
>>> c = C()
C::__init__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 4, in __init__
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

If I modify the `__init__` of `C` to

```
class C(B,A):
    def  __init__(self,):
      print("C::__init__")
      super(B, self).__init__('another')
      super(A, self).__init__('waaa')
```

I get the following when creating an instance of `C`

```
>>> C()
C::__init__
A::__init__ .... name = another
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 5, in __init__
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
>>>
```

## My questions

I read the document of [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#super) and it wasn't clear if it is possible to call the `__init__` of each respective child class.

It appears that the `super(B, self)__init__('another')` is actually calling the `__init__` of class `A`, while `super(A, self).__init__('waaa')` is calling the `__init__` of class `B`.

1. Why is `super()` not respecting it's `type` argument?
2. How can I create an object `C` that has all the class attributes and methods of both `A` and `B`?

Comment: The **whole point** of `super` is that you call it once, and all the inherited functionality (including multiple inheritance) is dealt with. This does mean that call signatures must match (or use `*args` and `**kwargs` to handle differences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `super()` incorrectly; it is not meant to call specific super methods explicitly, it is meant to search for the next method in the inheritance graph, dynamically. `super()` uses the type to find the place to start searching *from*, skipping the passed in type.

In this case, you can just call the parent `__init__` *directly*:

```
class C(B,A):
    def  __init__(self,):
      print("C::__init__")
      B.__init__(self)
      A.__init__(self, 'waaa')
```

Because your `__init__` methods have specific signatures, you cannot just use `super()`; your `__init__` methods need to fit one signature (which *could* be one that accepts arbitrary arguments and ignores what it doesn't need).

To be explicit, the first argument to `super()` tells it what type to **skip** when searching for the requested method, which is why you normally pass in the *current* class.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is `super()` not respecting it's `type` argument?

Because `super()` doesn't use the `type` argument as the type to use. Instead, it uses it to figure out which is the *next* type to use, according to [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). This is why you pass it the *current* type.

> How can I create an object C that has all the class attributes and methods of both A and B?

Have `A` and `B` use `super()` properly as well. Yes, it can make passing arguments to the constructor very difficult. No, there is no good solution other than "don't have different signatures for the constructors".